# Install Facebook sdk with use_frameworks! Coocapods

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am running a swift project. I need to use FacebookSDK along with others swift library.

When I use the use_frameworks! in Podfile. it gives the error file not found.

Here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod "Mobile-Buy-SDK"
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CocoaPods website the Facebook-iOS-SDK is deprecated.

You can try replace the pod for the 'FBSDKCoreKit', 'FBSDKLoginKit', and 'FBSDKShareKit' pods, see this [link](https://cocoapods.org/?q=FBSDKCoreKit).